# xpath with variable symbol. how do this?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, css-selectors

I have HTML code.

```html
<div _ngcontent-c30="" class="message__main"><p _ngcontent-c30="">Куплю</p><ul _ngcontent-c30="" class="message__conditions  list  list--inline"><!----><li _ngcontent-c30="" class="list__item ng-star-inserted"><p _ngcontent-c30="" class="list__key">Кол-во:</p><p _ngcontent-c30="" class="list__value">1 10³ м.</p></li><li _ngcontent-c30="" class="list__item"><span _ngcontent-c30="" class="point"></span></li><!----><li _ngcontent-c30="" class="list__item ng-star-inserted"><p _ngcontent-c30="" class="list__key">Цена за ед.:</p><p _ngcontent-c30="" class="list__value">1,00&nbsp;₽</p></li><li _ngcontent-c30="" class="list__item"><span _ngcontent-c30="" class="point"></span></li><li _ngcontent-c30="" class="list__item"><p _ngcontent-c30="" class="list__key">Сумма:</p><p _ngcontent-c30="" class="list__value">1,00&nbsp;₽</p></li></ul></div>
```

I need to check that the correct number is displayed (it is with a decimal part).

I think it’s wrong to contact the locator twice, expecting it to be right once. I want to do something like `contains(.,"^123(.|,)123$")`

so it is possible?
if not. how do it with another methods

Comment: Can you share source code (HTML/XML) sample along with current and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search number *11,27* ind `"div.message__main"`

In JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("div.message__main").innerHTML.match(/11(.|,)27/);
```

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 2.0 you can do

```
matches(., "^123(.|,)123$")
```

In XPath 1.0 you could try

```
translate(., ',', '.') = "123.123"
```

In SO questions, please always say which XPath version you are using, since 1.0, 2.0, and 3.1 are all in common use.

Comment: how to do it in this way "//tag[@class="class" and matches(., "^123(.|,)123$")]? it;s not work in Chrome

Comment: The built in XPath processor in Chrome is XPath 1.0, so you can't use my 2.0 solution (unless you install a third-party processor such as Saxon-JS).

Comment: okey. maybe then you can write it in JavaScript. pls. like that `document.FindElements().matchMyElement()` ?